# CodeIgniter Count Records for Query that Excludes Limit Condition

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I want to do two things in one query: use the limit() function, but also get the total number of records as a record count for the query, as if the limit wasn't used. So, if there are 21 total records that meet the conditions `like '%Gregory%'`, I would like that value returned, even though I'm using a `limit(10,0)`.

Here's my code:

```
    $data['recordcount'] = $this->db->count_all_results('assets');
    $this->db->limit(10, 0);
    if(isset($data['order'])){ 
        $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('assets')->or_like($array)->order_by($column, $data['order'])->get();
    }
```

The problem is that $data['recordcount'] in the first line returns all records. I want it to return all records that meet the query condition in the 4th line, but without the limit found in the 2nd line.

Comment: I would suggest that you use separate queries for that. Although that will you cost you a little extra resources.

Comment: @javiniar.leonard Yeah, I'm trying to figure out how not to use a separate query, but that may be the only solution in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally `count_all_results()` clears the select statement when run. But by setting the second parameter to FALSE the statement is retained.

I think this will work for you.

```
  $this->db->select('*')->from('assets')->or_like($array);
  $data['recordcount'] = $this->db->count_all_results('assets', FALSE);
  $this->db->limit(10, 0);
  if(isset($data['order']))
  {
    $this->db->order_by($column, $data['order']);
  }
  $query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve  **SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS** before the asterisk (*) like this:

```
 $this->db->select('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *')->from('assets')..etc
```

This will calculate the number of rows that would be returned without the LIMIT condition.

Immediately after that you can select the **FOUND_ROWS()** like this:

```
$this->db->select('FOUND_ROWS()')->get();
```

This will return you the number you are looking for.

For more information refer to this page
[enter link description here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)